# Query firstname, lastname as fullname

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get first name and last name as full name ,for that i am setting in model

```
      "chatBotId": String,
        "firstName":String,
        "lastName":String,
        "contactId" : String,
        "type" : String,
         "userId":String,
        "BotResponseBlocked": Boolean
    }
);

chatUserSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function(){

    return this.firstName+' '+ this.lastName;
})
```

But my query doesn't return the full name.

```
chatUsersModel.find({chatBotId:chatBotId},{'_id':0,'userId':1, 'firstName':1, 'lastName':1}).lean().
            exec((err,result)=>{

            callback(result);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **lean()** function means the results of your queries will be just JavaScript objects with none of the mongoose stuff.

This means that you won’t get virtuals.

You could remove **lean()** from your query or there is a plugin you can use to include virtuals in a lean query called **mongoose-lean-virtuals**:

```
const mongooseLeanVirtuals = require('mongoose-lean-virtuals')

// ...

chatUserSchema
  .virtual('fullName')
  .get(function() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
  })

// Use plugin after defining virtuals
chatUserSchema
  .plugin(mongooseLeanVirtuals)
```

You can tell **lean()** to include virtuals like this:

```
chatUsersModel
  .find({ ... })
  .lean({ virtuals: true })
  .exec((err, result) => {
    callback(result)
  })
```

This should now include your virtuals in your results.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`$concat`***](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) aggregation operator to get the `firstName` and the `lastName` as `fullName`

```
chatUsersModel.aggregate([{
  '$project' : {  
    'fullName' : {'$concat' : [ '$firstName', ' ' ,'$lastName' ]}
  }
}]);
```